# Appengine cloud endpoints client generation not generating source jar file

Tags: android, eclipse, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

GAE version: 1.8.2

The client library is not getting generated from morning today. I have tried deleting the endpoints-lib directory and tried re-generating the client code. No help.

1. The important thing is that there is ***no error in the log!***
2. The .properties file has this content:

   src=../libs-sources/nabthethief-deviceinfoendpoint-v1-20130726061953-java-1.15.0-rc-sources.jar

*But there is no such file! I think this is where the source is to be generated and that file is absent.*

As a result, all my imports (related to the library) are failing and all I see in my code-base are errors.

Anyone experiencing the same? Please help.

Comment: Me too!
I was feeling alone.

Comment: I have spend 4 hours trying to find what was wrong... we'll, at least we are not alone ;)
Also, I think that's the same question: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17874217/generate-cloud-endpoint-client-library-suddenly-stopped-working)

Comment: I created a Issue for this, go and vote:https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log&groupby=&sort=&id=9746

Comment: nice job, Dan. I don't know when they will look into this.

Comment: I spent most of yesterday on this (I have made other changes and thought them the culprit), but I was initially on 1.8.1 so this problem is not tied to 1.8.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A breaking change was introduced and has been rolled back. The root cause is still under investigation, but you should see the correct behavior now.

Comment: can you please take a look at this question?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35338516/how-to-use-google-cloud-endpoint-jar-lib-in-android-project