# How to use google cloud endpoint jar lib in android project

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I made a android project and a created a google cloud endpoint module in the same project. Now I want to separate the android project and the backend project.
So I changed this line inside app.gradle from:

```
compile project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')
```

to

```
compile files('libs/backend-android-endpoints.jar')
```

I copied backend-android-endpoints.jar from `backend/build/libs` to `app/libs`

Now when I compile the project, it doesn't compile and gives an error related to `Realm`, a library that I'm using.

So I think that the problem is with the jar library that I'm using.

Thanks in Advance